# Mysql select inside select optimization

Tags: mysql

i am running into a problem, i have huge database and now i cant make changes i need to process all this data first. Problem is that each query which is writen below takes about 1-2 Minutes. If anyone know how to make a optimized select i would apprichiate it.

```
select distinct x.peerId
,(select max(id) from checkPeer where peerId=x.peerId) as idd 
from checkPeer x where x.id>0 order by x.id desc
```

Is there way to optimize this select from below defined table?

```
CREATE TABLE `checkPeer` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`peerId` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`peerDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`peerUrl` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
`peerState` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
`peerMessage` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`peerResource` varchar(5000) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `peerId` (`peerId`),
KEY `peerUrl` (`peerUrl`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=688791 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using MySQL indexes, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580859/can-someone-recommend-a-good-tutorial-on-mysql-indexes-specifically-when-used-i) for further guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a few immediate suggestions, remove `DISTINCT` and try the following:

```
select x.peerId, x1.id as idd 
from checkPeer x 
left join
(
    select max(id) id, peerid
    from checkPeer
    group by peerid
) x1
    on x.peerid = x1.peerid
where x.id>0 
order by x.id desc
```

The above works great, if you wind up needing more fields but you stated you only need the two so you can try:

```
select peerId, max(id) as idd
from checkPeer 
where id > 0
group by peerid
```

Comment: nope that wont work i get duplicates then. in that table i have duplicate peerId's but id is auto increment primary.

Comment: @osdTech can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some sample data?

Comment: but if i add distinct again with your query then is good, i will try run it live and tell you results, thanks

Comment: wow nice site that sqlfiddle thanks :) here is link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecbbf/1/0

Comment: @osdTech do you need to return any other data besides these two fields?

Comment: @osdTech sure, post a new question and if I don't get it someone else will be able to help. :)

Comment: well its connected to this one the other select runned from php but for same thing you can see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eeba1/1/0

Comment: @osdTech check out this fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eeba1/18 -- it shows your version and the new version at the bottom

Comment: its one problem there, its giving max date of another peerId or if there is not another peerId's then is giving wrong not the max sorry i bother you :(

Comment: @osdTech I would suggest posting another question with the original queries in it. OR try playing with the `GROUP BY`, use `peerid` instead to see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Why not group by peerid and select the max(id)?

```
select peerId, max(id) as idd
from checkPeer 
  where id > 0
  group by peerid
  order by id
```

Comment: hmm this seams even faster than bluefeet provided, and both are 150% faster than what i did :(

Comment: great, actually your query traverses the table twice