# Extremely slow select query from 3 left joins

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, left-join

I have a very slow select query and I've tried a number of things to speed it up, but it still takes up to *minutes* to execute. I'll explain the tables and what I've tried. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to organize this rather simple query.

There are about 18000 rows.

#### The Query Explained

Essentially the **positions** are owned by **clients** who are owned by **brokers**, so to link the position to a broker, we go through the `clients` table. I am displaying positions with corresponding brokers and whether they are linked to another position via `covered_positions`, and what position is linked (if any).

#### Tables explained

- `positions` contains all the trades (stock/options) done by the clients. It has a PK `positionsID` (AI), but MySQL doesn't seem to recognize it as a *possible index*. EXPLAIN results below.
- `clients` contains all the client info (customers). It has PK `clientsID` (AI) which is a foreign key in `positions`.
- `login_users` contains the brokers (employees). It has PK `user_id` (AI) which is a foreign key in `clients` as `broker_id`.
- `covered_positions` contains the links (not hyperlinks) between 2-5 positions. It has PK `covered_id` (AI). The `linked_id*` columns are `positionsID`s that have been linked together.

#### The Query

```
delimiter $$

CREATE VIEW `main_join3` AS 
select `positions`.`id` AS `positionsID`,
`positions`.`order_list` AS `order_list`,
`positions`.`client_id` AS `client_id`,
`positions`.`client_name` AS `client_name`,
`positions`.`broker_name` AS `pos_broker_name`,
`positions`.`account_status` AS `pos_account_status`,
`positions`.`cost_basis` AS `cost_basis`,
`positions`.`cost_per_share` AS `cost_per_share`,
`positions`.`security` AS `security`,
`positions`.`security_type` AS `security_type`,
`positions`.`strike_price` AS `strike_price`,
`positions`.`option_type` AS `option_type`,
`positions`.`exp_month` AS `exp_month`,
`positions`.`exp_year` AS `exp_year`,
`positions`.`exp_date` AS `exp_date`,
`positions`.`buy_shares` AS `buy_shares`,
`positions`.`buy_date` AS `buy_date`,
`positions`.`buy_price` AS `buy_price`,
`positions`.`buy_commission` AS `buy_commission`,
`positions`.`buy_misc` AS `buy_misc`,
`positions`.`buy_cost` AS `buy_cost`,
`positions`.`sell_shares` AS `sell_shares`,
`positions`.`sell_date` AS `sell_date`,
`positions`.`sell_price` AS `sell_price`,
`positions`.`sell_commission` AS `sell_commission`,
`positions`.`sell_misc` AS `sell_misc`,
`positions`.`sell_cost` AS `sell_cost`,
`positions`.`loss` AS `loss`,
`positions`.`profit` AS `profit`,
`positions`.`funds_in_out` AS `funds_in_out`,
`positions`.`funds_in` AS `funds_in`,
`positions`.`funds_out` AS `funds_out`,
`positions`.`stop_order` AS `stop_order`,
`positions`.`notes` AS `notes`,
`positions`.`orange_highlight` AS `orange_highlight`,
`positions`.`date_created` AS `pos_date_created`,
`positions`.`date_updated` AS `pos_date_updated`,
`positions`.`created_by_id` AS `pos_cb_id`,
`positions`.`created_by_name` AS `pos_cb_name`,
`clients`.`id` AS `clientsID`,
`clients`.`broker_id` AS `broker_id`,
`clients`.`account_status` AS `clients_account_status`,
`login_users`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,
`login_users`.`user_level` AS `user_level`,
`login_users`.`username` AS `username`,
`login_users`.`name` AS `name`,
`covered_positions`.`id` AS `covered_id`,
`covered_positions`.`linked_id1` AS `linked_id1`,
`covered_positions`.`linked_id2` AS `linked_id2`,
`covered_positions`.`linked_id3` AS `linked_id3`,
`covered_positions`.`linked_id4` AS `linked_id4`,
`covered_positions`.`linked_id5` AS `linked_id5` 
from (((`positions` 
left join `clients` 
on((`positions`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id`))) 
left join `login_users` 
on((`clients`.`broker_id` = `login_users`.`user_id`))) 
left join `covered_positions` 
on(((`positions`.`id` = `covered_positions`.`linked_id1`) 
or (`positions`.`id` = `covered_positions`.`linked_id2`) 
or (`positions`.`id` = `covered_positions`.`linked_id3`) 
or (`positions`.`id` = `covered_positions`.`linked_id4`) 
or (`positions`.`id` = `covered_positions`.`linked_id5`))))$$
```

#### EXPLAIN Results

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  positions   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    18070   
1   SIMPLE  clients eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   blackri_posting.positions.client_id 1   
1   SIMPLE  login_users eq_ref  PRIMARY,user_id PRIMARY 4   blackri_posting.clients.broker_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  covered_positions   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    214
```

#### What I've tried

- Removing all columns from query that are not being used
- Creating the query as a view
- Analyzing and optimizing the database
- Changing servers

Any support is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please describe what you are trying to accomplish with this query?  i.e., what in real world terms is your desired output?  That will help us solve the problem rather than decipher the query.

Comment: Have you tried creating indexes for the columns you are using? Check out this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580859/can-someone-recommend-a-good-tutorial-on-mysql-indexes-specifically-when-used-i

Answer (score 1):

Although minor, you have way overused your parenthesis...  Here is revised from/join

```
from 
   positions
      left join clients
         ON positions.client_id = clients.id 
         left join login_users
            ON clients.broker_id = login_users.user_id
      left join covered_positions
         ON  positions.id = covered_positions.linked_id1
         or  positions.id = covered_positions.linked_id2  
         or  positions.id = covered_positions.linked_id3 
         or  positions.id = covered_positions.linked_id4
         or  positions.id = covered_positions.linked_id5
```

secondly, just for grins, try adding the MySQL keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" to your query...

SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN  (rest of query)

And third, your table "Covered_positions"
Do you have indexes on each of the linked_id columns. That will make your query crawl if no index is able to be utilized on the join.

Finally, if your covered positions table has the client ID, I would ABSOLUTELY add that as the first field in the index and include client ID on the join... this way, at a minimum you would be joining to the client first, then positions within that client.

Comment: DRapp thank you for your response. Please note: The parenthesis were generated by MySQL Workbench and were not in the original query. How would I add indexes to each of the linked_id columns?

Comment: create index name_of_index on covered_positions ( client_id (if available), linked_id1, linked_id2, linked_id3, linked_id4, linked_id5 )..  If you DO have client ID (as indicated here), adjust your query to be join on position.clientid = covered_position.clientid AND ( position... or position... or position...)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue using **triggers**. Instead of using those costly ORs, I simply added a column in `positions` called `link_id` where the `id` from `covered_positions` is added by using:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER covereds_after_insert
    AFTER INSERT ON covered_positions
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE positions
    SET link_id = NEW.id 
    WHERE positions.id 
    IN (NEW.linked_id1, NEW.linked_id2, NEW.linked_id3, NEW.linked_id4, NEW.linked_id5);
END
$$
```

AND

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER covereds_after_delete
    AFTER DELETE ON covered_positions
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE positions
    SET link_id = NULL
    WHERE positions.id 
    IN (OLD.linked_id1, OLD.linked_id2, OLD.linked_id3, OLD.linked_id4, OLD.linked_id5);
END
$$
```

This way the query doesn't turn 18,000 rows into about 4 million.