# Query Running Too Slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a C# WinForm Application that queries a MySQL database. The time it takes to query is unbelievable slow (30secs - 1min). I have very little experience with DB's and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my query. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong.

```
string sql = "SELECT t1.date, t1.name, t2.name, t3.addrs
              FROM tbl1 t1 JOIN tbl2 t2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
              JOIN tbl3 t3 ON t3.addrs = t2.addrs WHERE t1.date = '2013-04-01';";

string connStr = "Server = 10.10.10.100; Database = mydb; etc...";
MySQLConnection conn = new MySQLConnection(connStr);
MySQLCommand cmd = new MySQLCommand(sql, conn);
MySQLDataReader rdr = null;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Id","FirstName","LastName","Address","Date");

rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(rdr.Read())
{
    dt.Rows.Add(rdr["ID"], rdr["FirstName"], rdr["LastName"], rdr["Address"],rdr["Date"]);
}

conn.Close();
rdr.Close();

dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: @user....have you tried indexing your tables?

Comment: Please paste your code again, and this time, select the whole block, THEN click the code button!

Comment: How long does the query take to run manually?

Comment: MySql Performance post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580859/can-someone-recommend-a-good-tutorial-on-mysql-indexes-specifically-when-used-i

Comment: Also note that the string indexing needs to be of proper case sensitivity, otherwise it will be terribly slow. MySQL ADO.NET implementation is weird in this case. And its only for MySQL ADO, all other connectors I tested worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I would make sure you have indexes on the join fields and the date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `tbl2.addrs` is a unique key. If it's not, you're doing a cross join, which is both very expensive and probably not what you want anyway.

That said: make sure that you have indexes on `tbl1.id` and `tbl2.addrs`, and optionally `tbl1.date`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need table t3 in your query.  The only field you are selecting is addrs.  However since you are joining to t2 on that field, you can simply select it from t2.  This would be your query.

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.name, t2.name, t2.addrs
FROM tbl1 t1 JOIN tbl2 t2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
WHERE t1.date = '2013-04-01'
```

Also, this looks like a .net app.  Use query parameters.  One of their redeeming qualities is that they sometimes speed up queries.